# Split view controller navigation bar question

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

### Background:

I have a `UISplitViewController` showing a `UITabBarController` as its detail view (`.secondary`). The `UITabBarController` shows a `UIViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

### The plot thickens:

On iPad (not `.compact`), this works great. The `UINavigationBar` of the `UINavigationController` is shown as there is no push segue from the `UISplitViewController` as the views are `.tiled`.

However, on iPhone (.compact environment), this presents a problem. When `showDetailViewController:` is called, the `UISplitViewController` pushes the `UITabBarController`, which results in there being a *second* redundant `UINavigationBar` with a “Back” `UIBarButtonItem` for the `UISplitViewController`'s `UINavigationBar`, and then right under it is the `UINavigationBar` of the `UINavigationController`.

### Here’s what I’ve tried:

Removing the `UINavigationController` from the hierarchy fixes the issue on iPhone (or `.compact` environments), but introduces an issue on iPad (not `.compact`): no `UINavigationBar` from the `UISplitViewController` is shown at all.

Is there a straightforward solution/protocol for this? I feel as if though this is a pretty common scenario and I’m unsure how to move forward.

### The problem:

To reiterate, the goal is to have one UINavigationBar showing on both iPhone (`.compact`) and iPad (not `.compact`) for the detail (`.secondary`) view of my `UISplitViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else facing a similar problem (as any similar questions I've found on this site go unanswered), the solution was to instead embed the `UITabBarController` into a `UINavigationController`.

The `UISplitViewController` picks up the fact that it is pushing a `UINavigationController`, and merges the `UINavigationBar`s. In my original setup, the `UITabBarController` acted as a barrier and prevented the `UINavigationBar`s from merging.